# My object's grey colour has disappeared

Tags: 3d-view

Ok so I'm new with blender, as I was working on my project the object disappeared. The grey colour of the object disappeared. I can still see it just not the grey colour. Think I must have clicked or pushed something because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Ok so problem solved..vieportshading - Solid.

Comment: You've probably set your viewport shading to 'Wireframe'. Either select, say, 'Solid' from the 'Viewport Shading' rollout menu in the bar  at the bottom of the 3D View region - (just to the right of the Edit Mode/Object Mode etc. rollout) or hit 'Z' if your shortcut is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Just push <kbd>Z</kbd> in wireframe, which is where you are. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> from while in the rendering view will put you back in solid viewpoert