# All objects are just black lines in 3D view?

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view

[image: objects in 3D view]

I was quickly changing some text and not sure what button I accidentally clicked which caused this to happen, pressed <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> multiple times but nothing helped. Is there a way I can revert this back?

Comment: What is to be reverted is not clear at all. What do you expect? If it is solid shading, press Z.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108005/my-objects-grey-colour-has-disappeared/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the "*Bounding Box*" [shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html) mode.

Simply press <kbd>Z</kbd> twice and it will return back to the normal "*Solid*" shaded view.
Or you could just click on the Viewport Shading button in the 3D view's header, and then choose "*Solid*".
[image: Viewport Shading options]